# Multiple failures after installing I18n in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since I install I18n, some of my forms do no longer work. I realised that they are the one that include datetime inputs. Is there a step that I should add/amend in my setup? I am trying to create an record in my Blackoutperiods model.

My Blackoutperiod model look like this:

```
  create_table "Blackoutperiods", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "company_name"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "end"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

My controller look like this :

```
class BlackoutperiodsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_blackoutperiod, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @blackoutperiods = Blackoutperiod.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
    @blackoutperiods = Blackoutperiod.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @blackoutperiod = current_user.blackoutperiods.build
  end

  def edit
  end
  def update
    if @blackoutperiod.update(blackoutperiod_params)
      redirect_to blackoutperiods_path(@blackoutperiod)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def create
    @blackoutperiod = current_user.blackoutperiods.build(blackoutperiod_params)
    if @blackoutperiod.save
      redirect_to blackoutperiods_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def blackoutperiod_params
    params.require(:blackoutperiod).permit(:title, :company_name, :start, :end, :user_id)
  end

  def find_blackoutperiod
    @blackoutperiod = Blackoutperiod.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

my _form.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @blackoutperiod do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Title" %>
  <%= f.input :company_name, label: "Company name" %>
  <%= f.input :start, label: "Start" %>
  <%= f.input :end, label: "End" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-custom' %>
<% end %>
```

My Routes looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :blackoutperiods
    root to: redirect("/%{locale}/posts", status: 302)
  end
  root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}", status: 302), as: :redirected_root
  get "/*path", to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302), constraints: {path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/}, format: false
end
```

my models look like:

```
class Blackoutperiod < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :entreprise
end
```

I have

```
 class Entreprise < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :blackoutperiods
    end
```

And user `has_many blackoutperiods` of course. 
I have the following error:

```
Processing by BlackoutperiodsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXX", "blackoutperiod"=>{"title"=>"2018", "company_name"=>"ABC", "start(1i)"=>"2018", "start(2i)"=>"5", "start(3i)"=>"23", "start(4i)"=>"01", "start(5i)"=>"26", "end(1i)"=>"2018", "end(2i)"=>"5", "end(3i)"=>"23", "end(4i)"=>"01", "end(5i)"=>"26"}, "commit"=>"Create Blackoutperiod", "locale"=>"en"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering blackoutperiods/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered blackoutperiods/_form.html.erb (17.8ms)
  Rendered blackoutperiods/new.html.erb within layouts/application (37.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 574ms (Views: 515.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Comment: Please note that the INDEX and the SHOW work very well with some input that i made manually.

Comment: There's a rollback after creating something, have you seen if the records pass the validations?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, there is no input in the database. How do i see the "records pass validation" (sorry, I am new to Ruby"

Comment: Just put a `byebug` before `if @blackoutperiod.save`, the server will "stop" at that time and you can inspect the `@blackoutperiod` object with `@blackoutperiod.valid?`.

Comment: Ok let me try now

Comment: Like this ?

`[34, 43] in /Users/Etienne/ABC/app/controllers/blackoutperiods_controller.rb
   34:   end
   35: 
   36:   def create
   37:     @blackoutperiod = current_user.blackoutperiods.build(blackoutperiod_params)
   38:     byebug
=> 39:     if @blackoutperiod.save
   40:       redirect_to blackoutperiods_path
   41:     else
   42:       render 'new'
   43:     end
(byebug) @blackoutperiod.valid?
false
(byebug)`

Comment: Yep, you see there it returned `false`. So just use `@blackoutperiod.errors`.

Comment: Ok, it comes out as `(byebug) @blackoutperiod.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fb74e3f66e8 @base=#<Blackoutperiod >, @messages={:resource=>["must exist"], :entreprise=>["must exist"]}, @details={:resource=>[{:error=>:blank}], :entreprise=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>`

Comment: So, you have a couple of references values without specify "resource, enterprise".

Comment: Ok, now it works. I just understood a big piece of Ruby. Plus now I see how to check errors. THANK YOU. How can I accept your solution ?